# Does a Wireshark implementation exist for iPhone 4?

Tags: software-recommendation, iphone, applications, ios, wireshark

Does a Wireshark implementation exist for iPhone 4? I recently felt a need to have some tools with me at all times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a jail broken iPhone you can ssh into it and install tcpdump. Tcpdump is a command line program that wireshark is indirectly built off of.

Answer (score 3):

There's no WireShark app for iPhone no but there are a few Network Diagnostics tools which may do what you need since you don't state exactly what you want to do.  Take a look at [Network Diagnostics Utility Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/app/network-diagnostics-utility/id306478905?mt=8) which is $4.99 and might cover your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

pirni is an iOS packet capture tool that does ARP poisoning and can dump to PCAP for analysis in Wireshark on a desktop.

pirni-derv can do some basic analysis on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no official version of Wireshark on iPhone. However, there [is one for Macs](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).